# ActionScript - Get the names of the elements in the library or the names of "the link to AS3"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I would like to get the name of the elements in the library when this element is on the stage.
If I can't I would like to get the name of "The AS3 link".

[image]

I tried with this code:

```
for (var i=0; i<this.numChildren; i++){
    trace("Movie Name: "+this.getChildAt(i).name);
    trace("Movie Class: "+getQualifiedClassName(this.getChildAt(i)));
    trace("Movie Super Class: "+getQualifiedSuperclassName(this.getChildAt(i)));
}
```

But I only get this:
Movie Name: instance1
Movie Class: flash.display::Bitmap
Movie Class: flash.display::DisplayObject

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? Please elaborate on your goal. What do you want to do with the library name?

Comment: I don't know why you need that, but take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211001/flash-as3-getting-a-list-of-library-objects) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084097/how-to-list-objects-in-library-using-as3-at-runtime) may be you can find something.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to get the name from library. It is used only by the Flash IDE and it is not exported.

To get the class name from a bitmap in stage, you can try this:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = Bitmap(getChildAt(0)).bitmapData;
trace(getQualifiedClassName(bitmapData))
```

Answer (score 0):

In you library there are three images. Linkage name of the image represents a BitmapData class. You can't add BitmapData directly to the stage. Firstly, you create a BitmapData instance:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new SomeBitmapData();
```

SomeBitmapData it's a linkage name of the image.

[image]

Then you add an instance of Bitmap class:

```
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
addChild(bitmap);
```

If you want to get linkage name e.g. `SomeBitmapData` you should write:

```
trace(getQualifiedClassName(bitmapData)); // SomeBitmapData
```